# Whats the usage of metatables without metamethods?

Tags: lua

I started learning Prototype-based programming in Lua.  I wonder what's the usage of metatables without metamethods. There is a line in example below **self.__index = self** when I remove this line **somevalue** is not visible in my new object this is normal because I didn't use the metamethod __index. What's the usage of metatables then - to use metamethods only? Sorry for trivial question but this is really interesting, I know I can use getmetatable to check the metatable of some object. I need simple answer: There is no usage without metamethods or there is(if yes then what).

```
-- Example taken from the official documentation.
Account = { somevalue = 1 }

function Account:new (o)
    o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
    setmetatable(o, self)
    --self.__index = self
    return o
end

a = Account:new()
print(a.somevalue) -- nil, so I can't use any features of the metatable till I use some metamethod?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, metatables store metamethods. This does not mean that a metatable has to store *only* metamethods; several libraries use themselves as metatables.

A metatable is an ordinary Lua table. It only becomes the metatable of an object when you call `setmetatable` with it as its second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You can also make keys or values or both weak with the `__mode` metatable key, which takes a string value and not a function (method)

Most metamethods are explained here:

- [Lua Manual: Metatables and Metamethods](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4)

Some Lua API functions also test for specific meta methods, like

- `__pairs` - for pairs()
- `__ipairs` - for ipairs()
- `__tostring` - called by the tostring() function
- `__gc` - for garbage collection
- `__metatable` - read by the set/getmetatable functions (also a value)

If you search the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4) file for the specific name including `__` you will find the full definition and explanation, no use in repeating it here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, metatables store the metamethods of the object, and that's what they're used for, at least I haven't seen any other usecase.